# QR code-like alternative with extremely low error rate and ability to read bent codes

Tags: camera, qr-code, error-correction

I'm trying to find an alternative to QR codes (I'd also be willing to accept an entirely novel solution and implement it myself) that meets certain specifications.

- First, the codes will often end up on thin pipes, and so need to be readable around a cylinder. The advantage to this is that the effect on the image from wrapping it around a cylinder is easy to express geometrically, and the codes will never be placed on a very irregular shape.
- Second, read accuracy must be very high, as any read mistake would be extremely costly. If this means larger codes with more redundancy for better error correction, so be it.
- Third, ability to be read by the average smartphone camera from a few inches out.
- Fourth, storage space of around half a kilobyte per code.

Do you know of such a code?

Answer (score 1):

The Data Matrix Rectangular Extension (DMRE) improves upon the standard set of rectangular Data Matrix symbol sizes in an algorithmically compatible manner, thus increasing the range of suitable applications with no real downsides.

Reliable cylindrical marking is a primary use case.

Regardless of symbology you will be unable to approach sufficient data density to achieve 0.5KB of binary data in a single compact, narrow symbol scanned using a standard camera phone. However, most 2D symbologies (DMRE included) support a feature called Structured Append that allows chaining of multiple symbols that can be scanned in any order to produce a single read when all components are accounted for.

If the data to be encoded is known to be highly structured (e.g. mostly numeric or alphanumeric) then the internal encoding process of Data Matrix will be more optimised than for general binary data. For example, the largest DMRE symbol (26×64) will provide up to 236 numeric characters, ~175 alphanumeric characters and only 116 bytes.

If the default error recovery rate is insufficient then including a checksum in the data may be appropriate.

DMRE has just been voted to be accepted as an ISO/IEC project and will likely become an international standard enjoying broad hardware and software support in due course.

Another option may be to investigate PDF417 which has a broader range of symbols sizes, however the data density is somewhat less than Data Matrix.

DMRE references: [AIM specification](http://www.aim-d.de/images/stories/pdfs/Arbeitskreise/Barcode/aim_spec_dmre1%2001.pdf) and [explanatory notes](http://www.eurodatacouncil.org/images/documents/DMRE-explanatory_notes-150528.pdf).

Comment: As a point of curiosity, is there a significant disadvantage to using a 4-color system instead of 2-color? It would double data capacity for a seemingly small effect on readability

Comment: No particular disadvantage. The Ultracode symbology which has just been released as an ISO/IEC standard makes use of multiple colours to increase data density. I haven't reviewed the standard yet but I imagine it attempts to avoid readability issues due to coloured background lighting, etc. http://www.aimglobal.org/news/298285/Ultracode-Advances-Color-Barcoding-Using-Phone-App.htm